# How to filter my data.table by condition and by group?

Tags: r, filter, dplyr, data.table

## Problem

I work on a data.table where each row is a medical observation. The problem is there are some errors in my data, and I need to correct them before pursuit my analysis. For example, a male patient can have an observation where he is coded as a female.

## Solution

My solution is to select the mode (most frequent value) of a variable by the patient. If a patient has 10 observations as a male, and one as female, it is safe to assume that he is a male.

I have found that clever way to do it with data.table.

```
DATA[j  = .N, 
     by = .(ID, SEX)][i = base::order(-N), 
     j = .(SEX = SEX[1L]), 
     keyby = ID]
```

The problem is that when a patient as multiple modes, it just keeps one. So a patient which is 50% male and 50% female will be counted as a male, which will lead to a bias in the end. I would like to code them as NA's.

The only way to correct this I founded is by using dplyr

```
DATA[j  = .N, 
     by = .(ID, SEX)] %>% 
     group_by(ID) %>% 
     filter(N == max(N))
```

and then replace SEX value by NA if duplicated. But it takes way longer than data.table, it is not very optimized, and I have a big data set with a lot of variables that would need to be corrected as well.

## Resume

How do I took the mode of a variable by a patient and replace it by NA's if not unique?

## Example

```
ID <- c(rep(x = "1", 6), rep(x = "2", 6))
SEX <- c("M","M","M","M","F","M","M","F","M","F","F","M")

require(data.table)
DATA <- data.table(ID, SEX)

# First method (doesn't work)
DATA[j  = .N, 
     by = .(ID, SEX)][i = base::order(-N), 
     j = .(SEX = SEX[1L]), 
     keyby = ID]

# Second method (work with dplyr)
require(dplyr)
DATA[j  = .N, 
     by = .(ID, SEX)] %>% 
     group_by(ID) %>% 
     filter(N == max(N)) %>%
     mutate(SEX = if_else(condition = duplicated(ID) == TRUE,
                          true = "NA",
                          false = SEX)) %>%
     filter(row_number() == n())

# Applied to my data it took 84.288 seconds
```

## Update

Solution proposed by @Cole based on an idea of @Sindri_baldur :

```
DATA <- data.table(
 ID = c(rep(x = "1", 6), rep(x = "2", 6)),
 SEX = c("M","M","M","M","F","M","M","F","M","F","F",NA),
 V1 = c("a", NA, "a", "a", "b", "a", "b", "b", "b", "c", "b", "c")
)

our_mode_fac <- function(x) {
  freq <- tabulate(x)
       if (length(freq) == 0 || sum(freq == max(freq)) > 1 ) {NA}
       else {levels(x)[which.max(freq)]}
  }

vars <- c("SEX", "V1")

DATA[j = paste0(vars) := lapply(.SD, as.factor), 
     .SDcols = vars][j = vars := lapply(.SD, our_mode_fac),
                     .SDcols = vars, 
                     by = ID]
```

It works perfectly fine. It took the mode, even when there is more NAs than factors, and replace values by NAs when there is more than 1 mode.

Now it is also very fast : 11 seconds for 3M+ observations and 1M+ patients (117 seconds with @Sindri_baldur answer). Thanks a lot both of you I'm very grateful !

Comment: A basic reproducible data and example of expected output would help. A lot.

Comment: Done with a very basic example (because I'm a noob) ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
our_mode <- function(x) {
  freq <- table(x)
  if (length(freq) == 0 || sum(freq == max(freq)) > 1 ) {
    NA
  } else {
    names(freq)[which.max(freq)]
  }
}

vars <- c("SEX", "V1")
DATA[, paste0(vars, "_corrected") := lapply(.SD, our_mode), .SDcols = vars, by = ID]

    ID  SEX   V1 SEX_corrected V1_corrected
 1:  1    M    a             M            a
 2:  1    M <NA>             M            a
 3:  1    M    a             M            a
 4:  1    M    a             M            a
 5:  1    F    b             M            a
 6:  1    M    a             M            a
 7:  2    M    b             F            b
 8:  2    F    b             F            b
 9:  2    M    b             F            b
10:  2    F    c             F            b
11:  2    F    b             F            b
12:  2 <NA>    c             F            b
```

Reproducible data

```
DATA <- data.table(
 ID = c(rep(x = "1", 6), rep(x = "2", 6)),
 SEX = c("M","M","M","M","F","M","M","F","M","F","F",NA),
 V1 = c("a", NA, "a", "a", "b", "a", "b", "b", "b", "c", "b", "c")
)
```

Note that `our_mode()` is not optimised for speed. See suggestions by Cole for speed improvements in comments.

Comment: Same problem, it does not work as intended, and it is not very reproductible for variables with more than 2 factors.

Comment: @KévinLegueult Ok. so maybe your example data was too basic?

Comment: No it doesn't work on the example too, since there is no way to have NAs.

Comment: @KévinLegueult Updated to acommodate `NA`s. So you data has not only one messy variable (SEX) but many others and you want to apply the same method to them?

Comment: @KévinLegueult Made a new solution that can acommodate any number of variables.

Comment: Yes exactly. But the problem is not the NAs inside the variable. My problem is that sometimes, for a patient, there is 2 factors which could be considered as mode (most frequent value). In my example, the patient "2" as 3 observations as "male", and 3 observations as "female". Since it doesn't make sense, I need to ignore them (replace the values by NA).

Comment: @KévinLegueult THis solution does account for that.

Comment: So I tested it, it works perfectly fine (and it showed that my solution was bad if they were more NAs than factors, because it was counted as NAs, which leaded to a loss of information).

Comment: Could you explain what this is doing ? I struggle to understand what does .SD and .SDcols mean.

Comment: Converting the ```vars``` to factors and using ```tabulate()``` is around twice as fast on my computer. ```our_mode_fac <- function(x) { freq <- tabulate(x); ...; levels(x)[which.max(freq)]}; DATA[, (vars) := lapply(.SD, as.factor), .SDcols = vars]; DATA[, ... := lapply(.SD, our_mod_fac), ...]``` I couldn't find a different method that was unique enough to post a separate answer. +1

Comment: @KévinLegueult `.SD` is like another `data.table` with only the columns specified in `.SDcols`. Try `as.data.table(iris)[, .SD, .SDcols = c("Petal.Length", "Petal.Width")]`

Comment: Oh okay. Thanks for the help !

Comment: @Cole This is ten times faster. I will update my question thanks a lot !